# Access: How can I display a new record in one form after creating in a second form

Tags: ms-access, vba

Access 2007: I have one form with 100s of records displayed. I have a second form for editing or creating new records. When I return to the first form after adding a new record, I do On Activate: Me.Requery so the new record is added to the list, but I would like it to display on the screen with the record selector on the new record. Is there a way to do this? I am assuming that I save the ID in a global variable, but not sure what to do next. Thanks.

RESPONSE:
Thanks //t.  Your answer got me going in the right direction.  I will post my solution, which I think is more of a work-around.  There has to be a better solution, but this seems to work.

Form 1 (list) -> Form 2 (edit/new) and create new record.

```
Private Sub Form_Current ()
  glngID = Me.ID.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close
  gstrLastForm = "Form2"
End Sub
```

When I close Form 2, Form 1 is active.

```
Private lngSelectedRecord as Long

Private Sub Form_Activate()
  Me.Requery
  FindSelectedRecord
  If gstrLastForm = "Form2" Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Form1", acGoTo, lngSelectedRecord
  End If 
End Sub

Private Sub FindSelectedRecord()
  ...
  Open recordset, move through records, increment counter, exit when ID found
  ...
  lngSelectedRecord = intCounter
  ...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the on_close-method in your popup window to go to the inserted record,
something like:

```
private sub on_close()
  'maby first check we're not undoing..
  docmd.gotoRecord yourform,yournewid
  me.close
```

(on osx currently, but I hope you get the concept...)

Answer (score 3):

This is usually done with a form opened in dialog mode. In most cases, you'd have a command button on your main form ADD NEW RECORD, that when clicked would run code like this:

```
  DoCmd.OpenForm "MyAddForm", , , , acFormAdd, acDialog
```

This opens the form you use for adding a new record to a new, empty record, and pauses the code.

However, you need to know the PK of the record that was added, so you can't just close the form and let the code continue. So, the usual practice is to set the dialog form's Visible property to False, get the data out of it that you need, then close it and do what you want:

```
  Dim lngPK As Long
  DoCmd.OpenForm "MyAddForm", , , , acFormAdd, acDialog 
  If Forms!MyAddForm.Tag <> "Cancel" Then
     lngPK = Forms!MyAddForm!PK
     Application.Echo False 
     Me.Requery
     With Me.RecordsetClone
       .FindFirst "[PK]=" & lngPK
       If Not .NoMatch Then
          If Me.Dirty Then
             Me.Dirty = False
          End If
          Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
       End If
     End With
     Application.Echo True
  End If
  DoCmd.Close acForm, "MyAddForm"
```

In the dialog form, you have to hide the default window controls so the user can't close it. Instead, have two command buttons SAVE and CANCEL. The SAVE button does this:

```
  If Me.Dirty Then
     Me.Dirty = False
  End If.
  Me.Visible = False
```

...and the CANCEL button does this:

```
  Me.Undo
  Me.Tag = "Cancel"
  Me.Visible = False
```

The result is that you know that a record was not saved so you don't want to do anything to the calling form.

This is all standard Access user interface design, and it's by far the easiest and most bulletproof method for doing this kind of thing.