# Access 2007 Form 1 does not refresh when new records are added from Form 2

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have Form 1 (Part_Photos) with record source set to a table (tbl_Photos).
Tbl_Photos: Part_Number is text field, Picture is attachment field

Cbo_Parts is unbound and lists all parts in the table (Part_Number field), and when a part is selected, the attachment from the table shows in the Picture (Attachment) control.  List_Parts_Selected listbox is populated from the previous form and different record source, based on a user-selected list of parts to review, and is on this form for reference only (read-only control).

[image: Part_Photos form]

The user should verify whether or not the parts in the listbox are already in the table.  If not, then click on Add Record(s) command button.

```
Private Sub Cmd_Add_Click()

Dim ctrl As Control
Dim varItem As Variant

Set ctrl = Forms!CommercialSummary.List_PN

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Add_Part_Photos", acNormal, , , , acDialog

    'empty PN listbox on Form Add_Part_Photos
    Forms!Part_Photos.List_Parts_Selected.RowSource = vbNullString

    'Loop through selected PNs in Commercial Summary Form and copy to PN 
combo box in Photos form

    For Each varItem In ctrl.ItemsSelected
       Forms!Part_Photos.List_Parts_Selected.AddItem ctrl.Column(2, varItem)
    Next varItem

End Sub
```

Form 2 (Add_Part_Photos) then opens, with the same listbox as on Form 1 – again, for reference only to remind the user which parts were initially selected for review.  Form 2 has the same record source as Form 1.

[image: Add_Part_Photos form]

The user can double-click a part in the listbox to populate the textbox (Control Source = Part_Number).  The user then clicks in the Picture control to add an attachment (Control Source = Picture), and then clicks the Save Photo command button.  This is repeated for each part/photo combination to be added to the table.  Once finished adding photos, user clicks on Exit command.  Or a Cancel command can be initiated.

```
Private Sub Cmd_Save_Click()

    'Save the record.
    RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    'Load a new record after the save.
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_Exit_Click()

  If Me.Dirty Then
     Me.Dirty = False
  End If
  Me.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_Cancel_Click()

  Me.Undo
  Me.Tag = "Cancel"
  DoCmd.Close , , acSaveNo

End Sub
```

Upon returning to Form 1, only the last part added shows in the combo box.  How do I get ALL added parts to show up?  I tried adding this to the Form 1 On Activate event, but it did not work:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Also, not entirely related, but how do I prevent the attachment control from showing the first record in the table when I return to Form 1?  Currently, it does not show a blank record like it does when initially opened.
[image: Return to Form 1 - first picture in table displayed but PN's not updated]
Researching similar questions, I stumbled across this post and attempted to insert the code into my database:
[Access: How can I display a new record in one form after creating in a second form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984616/access-how-can-i-display-a-new-record-in-one-form-after-creating-in-a-second-fo)

```
  Dim lngPK as String
  If Forms!Add_Part_Photos.Tag <> "Cancel" Then
     lngPK = Forms!Add_Part_Photos!Part_Number
     Application.Echo False
     Me.Requery
     With Me.RecordsetClone
       .FindFirst "[Part_Number]=" & lngPK
       If Not .NoMatch Then
          If Me.Dirty Then
             Me.Dirty = False
          End If
          Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
       End If
     End With
     Application.Echo True
  End If

  DoCmd.Close acForm, "Add_Part_Photos"
```

When I do this, only the last record added shows up when I return to Form 1.

I am a beginner with VBA, and I know this is a long post, but I am trying to provide all the relevant data (which I've struggled with in my prior few questions).  Any wisdom that can be provided is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the "add new part form" as a modal dialog any further code you have in the original form isn't run until the modal form is closed.

If you were to requery your original form at that point it should include your new data.
You can also pass the new data back to the originating form maybe to a hidden control, then use that to point to the new data.

Comment: That works great! So one last thing - when I return to the Part_Photos form after adding new attachments, the Picture control still shows the attachment from the first record in my table, even though the combo box is empty. How do I return to that form and show a blank record until the user selects something from the combo box?  When the user exits the "Add_Part_Photos" form, the code hits `Forms!Part_Photos.Requery` and works well. But then I added `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec` and now the new parts do not show in the combo box again.

Comment: I think you would need requery the combobox as well, as it's underlying data will have changed.

Comment: Works perfectly!      `Forms!Part_Photos.Requery
    Me.Cbo_Parts.Requery
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`